# JNLP, ProcessBuilder and file hierarchy

Tags: java, java-web-start, processbuilder

Here's the picture:

I have a code split across some jars and libraries in the following hierarchy:

```
Main.jar
  ---lib
      |
      ------ Secondary.jar
      ------ Lib1.jar
      ------ Libx.jar
```

The main class in Main.jar calls another main class on Secondary.jar like this:

```
ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
commands.add("java");
commands.add("-cp");
commands.add("lib"+System.getProperty("file.separator")
+Secondary.jar+System.getProperty("path.separator")+"lib");
commands.add("<Secondary Main class cannonical path>");
System.out.printl(commands.toString().replaceAll(",",""));
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
pb.start();
```

When I run this from the IDE and/or command prompt (the command that the println output) it works fine. When ran from javawebstart that process fails because it can't find Secondary Main class in the classpath.

I suspect it is related to how JWS handles the downloaded resources and such.

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using a `ProcessBuilder` in this case instead of just directly loading/running the other classes?  Note that Sun made it impossible for an applet or JWS app. to determine the location on the local file-system at which the app. is installed.  It is none of the apps. business to know that.

Comment: That would explain it and confirm my theory. Directly running the class seems to work. Now need to see if my performance is not affected, which was the reason behind running it on a different process.

Comment: Performance is impacted, making the change useless now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sun made it impossible for an applet or JWS app. to determine the location on the local file-system at which the app. is installed. It is none of the apps. business to know that.

Comment: Include the part to directly run the class so I can award the answer.

Comment: Show the code of the class you wish to launch that contains a `main(String[])`.  BTW - do you control the code of the 2nd class?

Comment: Yes I do control all the code related to this question. Sadly the code is for a private project so I can't show it. Basically it opens a swing screen to display the progress of a downloads of some files. Not sure if that's helpful.

Comment: This update process seems to be leaking memory, so having it on a different JVM allowed me to kill it wen it was done taking the leak away with him. Running the class directly reverts the performance back to the original state.

Comment: I was able to fix the initial issue all together. Your answer is appropriate for my question.